# Estilização da cor da borda azul do input

Tags: css, html5

Olá, eu gostaria de saber como eu mudo a cor da borda azul do `<input>` que é ativado quando você clica nele e aparece o cursor para digitar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a propriedade `outline-color` do elemento:

```
outline-color: red; /* borda vermelha */
```

Um exemplo:

```css
input{
   outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Mas desta forma só irá funcionar no Chrome. Em outros navegadores será preciso utilizar o `:focus` e definir também a largura e o tipo da borda:

```css
input:focus{
   outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Então, para funcionar em todos os navegadores, utilize a opção do `:focus`.